# Rotating car steering wheel

Tags: modeling, animation

Is there any way in blender that if we rotate car tyres left or right, The steering wheel can also move in the same automatically?
Can someone please help me in achieving this.

Comment: hello, could you please show your armature? you should be able to dot it with a Copy Rotation constraint

Comment: I didn't rigged it till now because of this question that what if we have to do it before rigging.I will use rigacar addon to rig it.

Comment: so are you familiar with Copy Rotation? Because I guess it's the solution

Comment: Iam not familiar with it but will try it for sure and get back. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Atlast I figured out how to do it with copy rotation constraint. But the problem is when I join or make parent the steering wheel to the car the rotation messes up. Any ideas?

Comment: hello, it's a bit complicated without the object, could you please share a simplified version? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I uploaded the simplified version. https://pasteall.org/blend/c6ffc45b0b7c4cda9f43077ca0e75b62 I used left tyre copy rotation constraint in it. Want to merge steering wheel mesh to car base mesh without messing up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the following settings are working: set your *Copy Rotation* to *Mix > After Original* (*"After Original : The new rotation is added after the existing rotation, as if it was applied to a child of the constraint owner"*) and *Local Space / Local Space* (you can leave *World Space* for the wheel if necessary):

[image]

[image]

Both wheel and steering wheel are supposed to rotate on their own Z axis here but if the axis were not the same you could have given the steering wheel a *Transformation* constraint instead of a *Copy Rotation* constraint.

Comment: what do you mean by merge? Just parent wheel and sterring wheel to the car? If you want to merge in one object you need to parent the meshes to bones and use bone constraint

Comment: Ok I got this.At first I parented it without keep transform. That is the reason it didn't worked.And 
 Keeping both as local space doesn't work for me. It works when target is world space. Thanks a lot.