# How to transfer world rotation to local axis via drivers or constraints?

Tags: animation, constraints, drivers

I would like to drive/constrain a local rotation axis of an target object by using drivers or constrain modifiers. Is there a way to do this in Blender?

I can copy rotation values by using a copy rotation constraint but it works for world axis only. Even if I set local axis in target, the world axis be be influenced alyways. Is this a bug maybe?

**Situation:** *Imagine you have a car steering wheel and want to copy the rotation of one of your front wheels*.

Best wishes

Chris

Comment: hello, maybe this will help : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228806/rotating-car-steering-wheel

Comment: OK. It works. Thank you for the hint! It was my fault. I tracked the wrong object... it was a carelessness... :-)

Comment: Note: The linked solution above doesn't work correct if you've a driver added to the rotation axis of your wheel target. Just for info. So you have to create an invisible control dummy wheel without drivers. I'll show my solution in my upcoming tutorial on YouTube.